# How can I inspect the representation of a compiled type?

Tags: memory, rust

[The nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html) gives an interesting way of displaying how a struct will eventually be laid out in memory. It also says that for the default representation, no guarantees are made. While I can check alignment and size using `std::mem::align_of` and `std::mem::size_of`, is there a way of getting the exact way that Rust has laid out my struct/enum, e.g. a table with field names and offsets?

Comment: Do you mean at runtime or as the user that invokes the compiler (to print in the terminal)?

Comment: Preferably at runtime, but I was just thinking it might require me to dig into the generated assembly.

Comment: You can't use the information at runtime (it is erased), but you can make the compiler print it for you at build time.

Comment: That's good enough, how do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the compiler flag `--print-type-sizes` (requires nightly). If using Cargo, use `cargo rustc` (note it requires `cargo clean`, thanks @tifrel):

```rust
cargo +nightly rustc -- -Zprint-type-sizes
```

E.g.:

```rust
struct Foo(i16, i32);
fn main() { _ = Foo(0, 0); }
```

Output (`rustc +nightly -Zprint-type-sizes file.rs`):

```
print-type-size type: `Foo`: 8 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.1`: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.0`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     end padding: 2 bytes
print-type-size type: `[closure@std::rt::lang_start<()>::{closure#0}]`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
print-type-size     end padding: 8 bytes
print-type-size type: `std::result::Result<isize, !>`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
print-type-size     variant `Ok`: 8 bytes
print-type-size         field `.0`: 8 bytes
print-type-size type: `std::process::ExitCode`: 4 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.0`: 4 bytes
print-type-size type: `std::sys::windows::process::ExitCode`: 4 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.0`: 4 bytes
```

There are some hidden types from `main()`, and our type. We can see it is 8 bytes, with 4 bytes alignment (because of the `i32`). We can also see the compiler reordered the fields so that the `i16` comes last, and then 2 padding bytes. Note that it prints only used types (this is why we used it in `main()`), and prints monomorphized types (after generics are applied).

Another way to print more verbose and more specific type information, is to use the perm-unstable `rustc_layout` attribute:

```rust
#![feature(rustc_attrs)]
#[rustc_layout(debug)]
struct Foo(i16, i32);
fn main() {}
```

```
error: layout_of(Foo) = Layout {
           fields: Arbitrary {
               offsets: [
                   Size {
                       raw: 4,
                   },
                   Size {
                       raw: 0,
                   },
               ],
               memory_index: [
                   1,
                   0,
               ],
           },
           variants: Single {
               index: 0,
           },
           abi: ScalarPair(
               Scalar {
                   value: Int(
                       I32,
                       true,
                   ),
                   valid_range: 0..=4294967295,
               },
               Scalar {
                   value: Int(
                       I16,
                       true,
                   ),
                   valid_range: 0..=65535,
               },
           ),
           largest_niche: None,
           align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
               abi: Align {
                   pow2: 2,
               },
               pref: Align {
                   pow2: 3,
               },
           },
           size: Size {
               raw: 8,
           },
       }
 --> rs.rs:3:1
  |
3 | struct Foo(i16, i32);
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Note however this prints the unmonomorphized types, so `struct Foo<T>(T)` will print `layout error: Unknown(T)`. Because of that, it also doesn't require the type to be used.

Comment: I cannot edit your answer, but I think you should warn that using `cargo +nightly rust -- ...` will require a previous `cargo clean` or not emit the information.

Comment: Yup, good point. Will edit.

Comment: Besides saying thank you for an awesome answer, does perm-unstable simply mean that it's unstable and the Rust team decided to never stabilize it?

Comment: Yes, because it is used mainly to debug the compiler itself, and may be helpful for developers debugging their applications, but it is not something you should use in production.

Comment: "and may be helpful for developers debugging their applications, but it is not something you should use in production" even then it seems really dodgy unless you're trying to piece out fields being manipulated from assembly listings.